# session not working in post method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

session[:user_id] = user.id this session not working but its working in get method(login)

```
  # Working fine here
  # get 'users/login'=>'users#login'
  def login
    session[:user_id] = 1
  end

  # post 'users/auth'=>'users#loginpost'
  def loginpost
      user = User.authenticate(request.POST['name'], request.POST['password'])
    if user
      # But not working here:(
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "You are Successfully logged in ^^"
    else
      render html: '<strong>HTML String</strong>'
      #render users_login_url, :notice => "You are entered invalid email or password"
    end
  end
```

Comment: Please elaborate.  Is user not authenticating or are you getting successful login message but have determined that session hash is not populated.  If so, explain what you did to confirm.

Comment: @sjcoder can you try adding `puts 'USER EXISTS!'`  just above `session[:user_id] = user.id`, and check first if it executes the code inside the `if user` block?

Comment: use `params[:name]` and `params[:password]` and double check the params sent.

Comment: # post 'users/auth'=>'users#loginpost'
  # i tried this but its not working again
  `def loginpost
    session[:user_id] = 1
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "You are Successfully logged in ^^"
  end`

Comment: Jay-Ar Polidario thank you i will try